# Typing function definitions in Vim

Tags: javascript, vim

I'm newly excited about using Vim for all my programming needs, but I haven't yet managed to Google myself to a neat way of writing function definitions.

When typing a new function definition (I'm writing Javascript) I do this:

1. <kbd>i</kbd>`function foo(x) {}`<kbd>Esc</kbd> which leaves me in
   normal mode with the cursor between the braces.
2. Now <kbd>i</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> which puts the
   closing brace on a new line.
3. Finally <kbd>O</kbd> opens a new line above the closing brace with
   the cursor on that new line.

This seems inefficient. Is there a neater way? (ideally not involving `.vimrc` hacks, because I'm trying to learn as much 'vanilla' vim as I can)

Comment: it seems that you are looking for snipmate or neosnippet plugin. google the name, you will find the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>i</kbd>`function foo(x) {`<kbd>CR</kbd>
`}`<kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>

is the golfiest I can get to your goal (parentheses closed at all times) without editing `.vimrc` or installing plugins.

Comment: This gets an upvote for introducing me to Ctrl-O. Very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

*snippets* are like the built-in `:abbreviate` on steroids, usually with parameter insertions, mirroring, and multiple stops inside them. One of the first, very famous (and still widely used) Vim plugins is [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script%5fid=2540) (inspired by the *TextMate* editor); unfortunately, it's not maintained any more; though there is [a fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate). A modern alternative (that requires Python though) is [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script%5fid=2715). There are more, see [this list on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category%3aAutomated%5fText%5fInsertion).

There are three things to evaluate: First, the features of the snippet engine itself, second, the quality and breadth of snippets provided by the author or others; third, how easy it is to add new snippets.